# O que é uma query T-SQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, tsql

No [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), especificamente na primeira linha diz:

> *Click the Compose Query button up there and start typing your T-SQL query* [...]

Que em tradução livre seria:

> Clique no botão Compor *Query* acima e comece a digitar a sua *query* T-SQL [...]

---

- O que é uma query T-SQL?
- No que ela se diferencia de uma *query* normal?
- Que banco usa essa *query* T-SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Transact-SQL*, abreviado como **T-SQL** é propriedade da Microsoft e *Sybase* para a extensão SQL.

> **O que é uma query T-SQL?**

Uma *query* de SQL adaptada para o SQL Server.

> **No que ela se diferencia de uma query normal?**

- Controle do fluxo da língua
- Variáveis Locais
- Várias funções de suporte ao processamento de strings, datas, matemáticas, etc.
- Melhoramento para a declaração *DELETE* e *UPDATE*

> **Que banco usa essa query T-SQL?**

O SQL Server.

[Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL)